# Is it possible to forward all internet traffic through a software?

Tags: python, proxy

Is it possible to forward all internet traffic to a software - python, java, assembly etc. in order to manipulate the packets e.g. change the receiver IP to create a proxy?

Comment: in some programs (like web browsers) you can define proxy server or they may uses proxy settings in system - and then you can use own local proxy server like [mitm-proxy](https://mitmproxy.org/) or [charles proxy](https://www.charlesproxy.com/) or write own proxy (using any language which you like) to manipulate settings. For other you can try to use library [pcap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pcap) and programs like [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/)

Comment: How deep can I go with python on it's circumstances, my assumption was that i'll have to write a virtual network adapter or idk.. If you say there is a way could you link me to some theory or write what the structure would be?

Comment: [mitm-proxy](https://mitmproxy.org/) is created in Python, [scapy](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) can works with raw sockets/packets in Python, But I don't know how to write adapter. Many programs use `pcap` to catch all traffic but I don't know if they can modify it. See in wikipedia [pcap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pcap) for programs which use it and modules for different languages.

Comment: Probably it should be easy to create normal proxy server which can works with web browser or programs which use system settings and use proxy configures in system - [Creating a Proxy Webserver in Python](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/creating-a-proxy-webserver-in-python-set-1/) - but I don't know if all programs uses system settings.

Comment: Thanks alot, stay safe.